# Mongo DB - fastest way to retrieve 5 Million records from a collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, database

I am using MongoDB in our project and I'm currently learning how things work

I have created a collection with 5 million records. When i fire the query `db.ProductDetails.find()` on the console it takes too much time to display all the data.

Also when i use the following code in C#

```
var Products = db.GetCollection("ProductDetails").FindAll().Documents.ToList();
```

the system throws `OutOfMemoryException` after some time..

Is there any other faster or more optimized way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to fetch 5 million records at a time???

Answer (score 4):

Never try to fetch all entries at the same time. Use filters or get a few rows at a time.

Read this question: [MongoDB - paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049992/mongodb-paging)

Comment: Actually i need entire collection at once initially

Comment: which provider do you use to fetch all objects? and how large are each object?

Comment: I use the following Code Mongo firsttest = new Mongo(); firsttest.Connect(); var db = firsttest.GetDatabase("myDB"); var Products=db.GetCollection("ProductDetails").FindAll().Documents.ToList();

Comment: which provider (like NoRM) do you use to fetch all objects? and how large are each object (in bytes) ? And ***why*** do you need to fetch all objects?

Comment: I use MongoDBDriver-Release-0.90.0-Beta-1 which is suggested at mongodb.org.
The Collection contain following Column
Person,Product,Contient,Country,State,City,Qty,Amount

Comment: var Products=db.GetCollection("ProductDetails").FindAll().Documents

This line is executed within no time. But how should i convert the Products variable to any list or array type ?Converting takes time here

Comment: Why do you need to fetch all objects? Why can't you fetch a few items at a time? Deserialization will take a lot of memory and so will keeping 5M entities in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the subset which is needed. If you try to fetch all objects, then it is for sure you will need enough RAM as the size of your database collection !!
Try to fetch the objects which will be used in the application.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Don't forget to visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).