# DataGrid Pagination using Mongo dB

Tags: wpf, mongodb, pagination

I've a wpf app and mongo db as back end, if i call a query to mongo db from wpf app it giving me million of records so currently i'm using normal pagination like storing all data from db into data table and doing pagination. But if system having less memory its impossible to store that much of records, so some body says to me that mongo db provides pagination means we can call records directly from db when user clicks next or previous so any one help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongodb's [limit() and skip()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Blimit%28%29%7D%7D) to implement paging. For example, to get the 3rd page where page size is 10, you'd use this query:

```
db.your_collection.find().skip(20).limit(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of paging:

1. Via [limit](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Blimit%28%29%7D%7D) and [skip](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bskip%28%29%7D%7D), just like @milan proposed.
2. Via range query:

   `db.items.find({created: {$gt: startDate, $lt: endDate})`

Range queries will work faster then skip, because they are no need to move towards '*skip*' item.

Look into related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049992/mongodb-paging) as well.

For your case if you have only *next/prev* buttons range paging should be good option.

Comment: can you plz provide me sample for range paging.

Comment: @nag: see mongo shell example in my answer above.