# Pagination for WPF DataGrid using MongoDB(c#)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a Datagrid.Backend i am using MongoDB.I heard that MongoDB supports Pagination ie we did not retrive all data.We have to set itemsPerPage.Then client send pagenumber as input.Depending on input no o records are retrieved.So that for large volume of data system do not crash.I found one query from this forums.

[DataGrid Pagination using Mongo dB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801850/datagrid-pagination-using-mongo-db)?

query is

```
db.your_collection.find().skip(20).limit(10)
```

When i wrote above query limit(10) is not coming while type in visualstudio(intelligence is not coming)

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SetSkip(skip: int)` and `SetLimit(limit: int)` methods in the `MongoCursor` class to get your job done.

e.g.:

```
var results = collection.Find().SetSkip(20).SetLimit(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip and Limit are properties on the cursor so you would have to do something like this with the C# driver.

```
var cursor = collection.Find();
cursor.Skip = 20;
cursor.Limit = 10;
return cursor.ToList();
```