# How to make pagination with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to make a pagination feature in my Collection. How can find a documents with 'start' and 'limit' positions and get total document number in a single query?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't get both results in one query; the best you can do is to get them both using one Mongoose [`Query`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) object:

```
var query = MyModel.find({});
query.count(function(err, count) {...});
query.skip(5).limit(10).exec('find', function(err, items) {...});
```

Use a flow control framework like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) to cleanly execute them in parallel if needed.

Comment: When I run this the exec in the second query returns the same as the count... Does the count function modify the original query??

Comment: @ZekeAlexandreNierenberg You're right, Zeke; that must have changed as some point.  I updated the example to add the `'find'` parameter to the `exec` call to make it work with Mongoose 3.6.20.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the plugin [Mongoose Paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate):

```
$ npm install mongoose-paginate
```

After in your routes or controller, just add :

```
Model.paginate({}, { page: 3, limit: 10 }, function(err, result) {
    // result.docs 
    // result.total 
    // result.limit - 10 
    // result.page - 3 
    // result.pages 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to have a lot of pages, you should not use skip/limit, but rather calculate ranges.

See Scott's answer for a similar question: [MongoDB - paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049992/mongodb-paging)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE :**

Using skip and limit is not good for pagination. [Here is the discussion over it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049992/mongodb-paging)

@Wes Freeman, Gave a good answer. I read the linked pose, you should use range query. n = 0; i = n+10; db.students.find({ "id" : { $gt: n, $lt: (n+i)} } );

**OLD ANSWER** (don't use this)

use something like

```
n = db.students.find().skip(n).limit(10);
//pass n dynamically, so for page 1 it should be 0 , page 2 it should be 10 etc
```

more documentation at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but need need to get total document count.

Comment: total = db.students.find().count()

Comment: Wes Freeman, Gave a good answer. I read the linked pose, you should use range query.
n = 0; i = n+10;
db.students.find({ "id" : { $gt: n, $lt: (n+i)} } );

Comment: As jackalope points out in one of the answers to that post, the calculated range strategy falls apart if you have a lot of sorting options or if what you're sorting on allows duplicates.  It just depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
   user.find({_id:{$nin:friends_id},_id:{$ne:userId}},function(err,user_details){
    if (err)
    res.send(err);
    response ={
        statusCode:200,
        status:true,
        values:user_details
    }
    res.json(response);
   }).skip(10).limit(1);
```

Comment: Your answer can be the correct one, but please try to add more context, to your code to help everyone that might be looking for the same.
Please refer to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please explain what the code in your answer does so people with low knowledge in the involved technologies have a chance to understand and re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function,

You can check if prev and next data is available or not.

```
async (req, res) => {
let { page = 1, size = 10 } = req.query
page = parseInt(page)
size = parseInt(size)
const query = {}
const totalData = await Model.find().estimatedDocumentCount()
const data = await Model.find(query).skip((page - 1) * size).limit(size).exec()


const pageNumber = Math.ceil(totalData / size)
const results = {
    currentPage: page,
    prevPage: page <= 1 ? null : page - 1,
    nextPage: page >= pageNumber ? null : page + 1,
    data
}
res.json(results) }
```

To know more [estimatedDocumentCount](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/)