# MongoDB. Index was out of range

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I keep having this error as I try to retrieve thousands of documents from the collection.

```
index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. parameter : Index
```

Here is my code as I query the documents:

```
        MongoCollection<Book> collection = PDatabase.GetCollection<Book>("books");
        List<IProduct> products = new List<IProduct>();
        var books = collection.Find(Query.GT("stock", 0)).SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout);
        foreach (var book in books)
        {
            try
            {
                products.Add(book);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  }
        }
        return products;
```

As I looked at the exception message, it says "index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter : Index"

Comment: what does `collection.Find` return?

Comment: I have a 'Book' class which i used as I initialize MongoCollection. So .find will return a list of 'Book'. And 'Book' implements my 'IProduct' interface

Comment: `PDatabase.GetCollection<Book>("books")` retuns anything?obviously `products` is not valid in the context

Comment: I editted it. Its 'books' where each book added to the Iproduct list.

Comment: the `try` shouldn't execute if `books` is null.. :(

Comment: each iteration of the books as when it goes to catch I actually see the current book having values. So its not null.

Comment: can you try putting the `foreach` inside `try`?

Comment: Instead of printing the ex.Message, just print "ex". It will include the stacktrace. It'll point to where the exception is coming from. Please update description with that information as well.

Comment: The main error is "An error occurred while deserializing the "property" property of class ''class": Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown". Its because of the huge number of documents queried. I tried limiting the query (eg: .SetLimit(100) ) and it works.
I wonder how to deal with this huge documents that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention in the comments that the underlying issue is an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer here suggests paging best practices [MongoDB - paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049992/mongodb-paging)

Comment: I dont use paging. I bet the error is about the size of List<Iproduct> which is millions since my documents is more than 6 million.

Comment: I was suggesting paging may benefit you. What are you hoping to do with 6 million documents anyway?

Comment: Thank you, I solved it using skip and limit. This way not all documents are loaded in one query.