# Querying the database throw an exception

Tags: c#, mongodb

When I return about 200,000 records to client the service works fine. But increasing the returned data(to 1 million) set causes below exception on server side:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Server instance localhost:xxxx is no longer connected. 
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.AcquireConnection(MongoDatabase database) 
in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp driver\Driver\Core\MongoServerInstance. cs:line 288
```

Somewhat happened when querying the database.
I have the latest MongoDb driver. `ConnectionPoolSize = 900` `ConnectionTimeoutSeconds = 3000`

Comment: what purpose does returning 1000000 records serve? It's not human-readable. Return your results in batches.

Comment: I have a huge number of events in my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your data in smaller chunks/pages. See this question for more information:

[MongoDB - paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049992/mongodb-paging)

In short, you can do something like this:

```
int currentOffset = 0;
int recordsFetched;
do
{
    var results =
        collection.Find(query)
                  .SetSkip(currentOffset)
                  .SetLimit(100)
                  .ToList();

    currentOffset += 100;
    recordsFetched = results.Count;

    // Process your data here.
} while(recordsFetched > 0);
```

Comment: Do you now how to do this?