# Is there a .startAfter fireStore equivaluent option in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, google-cloud-firestore

By default, I can use _id value in find() and sort() to skip documents. But, I am sorting using a different field. And hence the documents will be randomly sorted based on _id value.

I am looking for something equivalent of this

```
db.collection("cities")
                .orderBy("population")
                .startAfter(lastVisible)
                .limit(25);
```

Couldn't find an equivalent option in mongodb documentation. Kindly help with this query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Similar query in MongoDB would be:

```
db.collection('cities')
  .find({population: {$gt: lastVisible}})
  .sort({population: 1})
  .limit(25)
```

of course the actual query will depend on other things, but in general it will look like that. Create an index on `population` to ensure the query won't be a collection scan.

See [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) and [Create Indexes to Support Your Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/index.html)

**Note 1**: If you're new to MongoDB, please take a look at free courses in [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/) to learn more about MongoDB.

**Note 2**: *Don't use skip+limit for paging*. This is a known anti-pattern. See [MongoDB - paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049992/mongodb-paging) and 
[Paging with the Bucket Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1) for more information.

Comment: Note 2 is really helpful.